# I am trying to split while I am writing Ints to convert decimal to binary

Tags: c#, split

I am trying to convert from decimal to binary and i don't know how to split from one octat to another.

Here is my code:

```
        int oct = 0;
        int bin = 128;
        string resul = "";
        Console.WriteLine("insert ip address");
        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
        oct = int.Parse(temp);


        while (bin > 0)
        {
            if (oct >= bin)
            {
                resul += "1";
                oct = oct - bin;
            }

            else
            {
                resul += "0";
            }

            bin = bin / 2;

        }                       

         {
            Console.WriteLine(resul);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: How about `IPAddress.Parse` ?

Comment: can you show me how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
oct = int.Parse(temp);
string resul = Convert.ToString(oct ,2);
```